# CSS nav bar with linear gradients not showing background in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdPDR/)

I'm working on a personal site, and am using linear graidents for styling the nav bar.  However, the styling is breaking in Chrome while working in Firefox.  In Chrome, the main nav bar coloration is white and the text disappears on hover.

```
nav ul {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(center top , #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  .. other style settings

}
```

What alterations do I have to make to make this CSS Chrome-compatible?

Comment: If you go to colorzilla web, (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) there is a gradient generator that will do that for you automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Chrome doesn't process the `center` property of `-webkit-linear-gradient` style. In fact, if you open Chrome's developer tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> then go to the Console and turn CSS logging on, you'll get the following message:

> Invalid CSS property value: `-webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #4F5964 0%, #5F6975 40%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Chrome does, however, simply accept the `linear-gradient` CSS property ([and has done for a while](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)). You should be using this anyway for when those prefixes are finally dropped. Rather than using `center top`, you can simply use `to bottom` instead:

```css
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%)
                                              repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QdPDR/3/).

---

As a side point, you may as well replace all your `center top` declarations with `to bottom`:

```css
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: linear-gradient(to top , #EFEFEF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```